Proving that negative axioms don't break canonicity
In Negative consistent axioms can be postulatedwithout loss of canonicity, the authors show that if $\lnot P$ is a consistent axiom with MLTT, then MLTT+$\lnot P$ still has canonicity of $\mathbb N$. Paraphrasing a bit, they argue as follows:

Let $n:\mathbb N$ be a closed term, which by the normalization theorem we may assume is in normal form. As there is no closed term of type $P$, this normal form cannot contain any constant $p : ¬P$, so it has to be a numeral.

This seems right to me, but I'm not sure what the precise chain of implications is. One  possible intermediate step is

Let $r:A \to B$ be a closed term. If $t : \mathbb N$ is a closed term in normal form and $r$ appears in $t$, then $r$ is being applied to some term $k : A$.

This seems plausible to me, but then I don't know how to argue that this is correct. Is this what the authors may have had in mind? If so, why would this be the case?

I think this is not true in general. Say you have axioms $x : (A → B) → C$ and $y : A → B$, then in $x y$ the term $y$ is not applied to anything. But you can probably look at an "outermost" application of an axiom in the normal term.

You're right! I'm not sure what the intermediate step should be then (if any).

I am relating Martín Escardó's coment about the question:

This has been formalized in Agda by Andreas Abel. with the gaps filled:
https://github.com/andreasabel/logrel-mltt/tree/master/Application/NegativeAxioms

It's 220 lines of Agda with nice comments in the README file, so worth checking out.

You proof strategy is valid, let's complete it.
Assume $a : \neg P \vdash n : \mathbb{N}$, ie we have a "closed" natural number $n$, but which uses axiom $a : \neg P$. By normalisation, we can assume that $n$ is in normal form. From the definition of normal forms at $\mathbb{N}$, there are two possibilities:

either $n$ is a numeral $S^k(0)$, in which case we are done;
otherwise, $n$ must be of the form $S^k(n')$ with $k$ an (external) natural number and $n'$ a neutral, let us show this case is impossible.

Neutrals always are of the shape $E[x]$ where:

$x$ is a variable
$E$ is an evaluation context, ie a (possibly empty) list of eliminations ($- t$, $π_i -$, $\mathrm{rec}_{\bot}(-,A)$, $\mathrm{rec}_{\mathbb{N}}(-,P,b_0,b_S)$, etc.)

Here the only variable in context is $a$, so $n'$ must be of the form $E[a]$ for some evaluation context $E$.
$E$ cannot be empty, because otherwise we would have $n' = a$ thus $a : \neg P \vdash a : \mathbb{N}$, and therefore $\vdash \neg P \equiv \mathbb{N}$, which is impossible by no-confusion of type constructors. Moreover, again because of typing constraints, the innermost elimination in $E$ must be an application, ie $n'$ must actually be of the shape $E[a~p]$ (if it was for instance a projection, we would have $\neg P \equiv \Sigma x : A.B$ for some $A$ and $B$, which is not possible, again because of no-confusion). Eliminations never bind variables in their "main" argument, so $p$ lives in the same context as $n'$, and as an argument to $a$ must have type $P$.
We have obtained some $p$ such that $a : \neg P \vdash p : P$. Now we are almost done. First, we get $\vdash \lambda a. p : \neg P \to P$. But it is a theorem of MLTT that $(\neg P \to P) \to \neg \neg P$, for any type $P$. Thus, applying this to the above, we get that $\neg \neg P$ is derivable, thus $\neg P$ is not a consistent axiom, contradicting our hypothesis.

Amazing argument! A bit off topic, but do you have any recommended source for learning about syntactic properties of MLTT, and how to argue effectively about them?

@FernandoChu I don't really know about good sources on this, there is a lot of literature, but not much more "accessible" things… Maybe looking at PhD theses would be a good place to have a bit more context/gentle introduction?

People used to write books.

Tooting my own horn, here's some notes I wrote a while back: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GjSoS65mKFeBQS4uQ4eOLo__iihDZbUV/view?usp=drive_link. I based some of this on this incredibly thorough dissertation: https://www.cse.chalmers.se/alumni/davidw/wdt_phd_printed_version.pdf I highly recommend a read it is remarkably detailed.
